# Error when running nucleus-styleguide

Tags: node.js

I'm try to use nucleus to make styleguide. Install step by step according official page [link](https://holidaypirates.github.io/nucleus/installation.html).

Their site is pretty good, but there is a lack of documentations outside. So maybe someone help here :)

When I run (npm run styleguide) I get an error:

```
Mac-Admin:nodesubsite3 admin$ npm run styleguide
```

> sub-fortunalivecomua@0.0.0 styleguide /Users/admin/IdeaProjects/nodesubsite3
>   nucleus --config config.nucleus.json

```
/Users/admin/IdeaProjects/nodesubsite3/node_modules/glob/sync.js:30
throw new Error('must provide pattern')
^

Error: must provide pattern
at new GlobSync (/Users/admin/IdeaProjects/nodesubsite3/node_modules/glob/sync.js:30:11)
at Function.globSync [as sync] (/Users/admin/IdeaProjects/nodesubsite3/node_modules/glob/sync.js:25:10)
at Object.Config.getFilesFromGlob (/Users/admin/IdeaProjects/nodesubsite3/node_modules/nucleus-styleguide/src/Config.js:120:26)
at Object.Config.parse (/Users/admin/IdeaProjects/nodesubsite3/node_modules/nucleus-styleguide/src/Config.js:86:31)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/IdeaProjects/nodesubsite3/node_modules/nucleus-styleguide/index.js:41:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)

npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "styleguide"
npm ERR! node v6.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! sub-fortunalivecomua@0.0.0 styleguide: `nucleus --config config.nucleus.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sub-fortunalivecomua@0.0.0 styleguide script 'nucleus --config config.nucleus.json'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the sub-fortunalivecomua package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     nucleus --config config.nucleus.json
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs sub-fortunalivecomua
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sub-fortunalivecomua
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/admin/IdeaProjects/nodesubsite3/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from the `config.nucleus.json` file generated by the wizard. Since you left the parameter "files" blank, it inserted this block of code in json :

```
"files": [
  ""
],
```

Just remove it and it will compile just fine.